# Closure execution

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I have a function which executes a closure.

```
func callWebServiceToFindLocation(limitedClLocations: [CLLocation]) {
//      self.view.showLoaderWithMessage(FRDMessageConstants.pleaseWaitWhilecollectingGPSCoordinates)
        FRDRouteDirectionServices.getRoutesWithLocations(limitedClLocations, travelMode: TravelMode.TravelModeWalking, completitionBlock: { (routes) in

//            self.routes.arrayByAddingObject(routes)
//            print("\(self.routes.count)")
            FRDMapUtilities.sharedInstance.plotPolyLineOnMap(routes as! NSArray, viewMap: self.viewMap)
            FRDMapUtilities.sharedInstance.addMarkerAndSetAllMarkerBoundToScreen(self.clLocations, viewMap: self.viewMap, allStoreDetails: self.allStoreDetailsForMarker, myLocaion: self.myLocation)
            self.view.hideLoader()
            }, andErrorBlock: { (error) in
            self.showRefreshButton()
            self.view.hideLoader()
        })
    }
```

Now this function will be called twice `callWebServiceToFindLocation()` for certain reasons and then I've to call this `plotPolyLineOnMap` only once hence i was appending the routes returned in `FRDRouteDirectionServices.getRoutesWithLocations(limitedClLocations, travelMode: TravelMode.TravelModeWalking, completitionBlock: { (routes) in`
 into a global array.
Now i know that execution of closure takes place asynchronously. How can i call `plotPolyLineOnMap` only once for the global array of the routes.

Answer (score 0):

Check condition in closure

```
let arrayRouts : NSArray = routes as! NSArray

if arrayRouts != nil && arrayRouts.count > 0 {
self.routes.arrayByAddingObject(routes)
self.plotPolyLineOnMap()
}
```

When first time closure will get called that time routes will be nil and second time routes will have responce data so this condition should work.

Comment: it is of type AnyObject hence this comes "Value of type 'AnyObject' can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed"

Comment: Press command and click on completitionBlock  and check what is a return type of completitionBlock then convert routes in that type (For example if return type is array Then convert routes in array) like :- routes as! NSArray then compare it to nil.

Comment: the signature is getRoutesWithLocations(locations: [AnyObject],
        travelMode: TravelMode,
        completitionBlock: (routes: AnyObject) -> Void,
        andErrorBlock errorBlock: (error: AnyObject)-> Void)

Comment: Try Updated answer.